# How to ignore empty parquet files when reading using Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

I am using Hive 3.1.0 and my query reads a bunch of parquet files from certain path every hour. I don't have control over how these files are generated as these are created by some external process. In some rare case it happens that within the specified path a certain parquet file may exist with zero size. I would like Hive to ignore this but my hive queries fail with the following error:-

```
<filename>.parquet is not a Parquet file (too small length: 0)
```

How do I avoid this ? There could be too many files landing in an hour , so it would be an overkill to create automation to detect and delete empty files. I believe there should be some simpler option in Hive to make it just ignore such files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the property $file_size. If it is more than 0 then process the data load. It would be better if you can provide the query as how you are trying to access.

Comment: I didn't get it , can you please elaborate ? Property of what ? Is it some option I can set in hive ? My query is just a simple INSERT OVERWRITE <table> SELECT ... FROM ExternalSourceTable. The external source table points to the location where the parquet files are stored in year/month/day/hour sort of partitioned structure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this as hive property. If ever, you might want to handle empty files in a separate directory before pushing to final storage using:

`find ./your-directory -type f -empty -print -delete`

or if not possible, handle deleting files in your final storage.

Try to list the files to be deleted for sanity check.

Comment: these files are not in HDFS , these are in ADLS Gen2 (Azure Storage)

Comment: My bad, I just assume it. Not familiar with Azure storage, but similar principle probably can apply if you want to go that route.